# Garden trellis design, tips on the lattice

Tags: design

As a wood working project, I'd like to build a custom garden trellis. Trellis design looks roughly like this (sketch):

[image]

I've got all the outer dimensions, thickness of the wood, spacing between the diagonal pieces, angles, etc. For the diagonal sections, the idea is to pre-cut them all to the right length, and then to assemble the frame (unless you've got a better suggestion).

The only thing I don't have is the lengths of the diagonal sections. I could use some good old-fashioned calculus to calculate the lengths of the sections, but I was wondering how you would do it? Is there for instance a computer-aided design program that could automatically compute the lengths of the diagonal sections? Or what if I'd like to try out some alternative designs, e.g. different outer dimensions while keeping the inner lattice frame the same pattern. Is there a way to do this using software? Doing this by hand and re-calculating the lengths would be rather tedious.

This is what a store-bought trellis looks like:

[image]

Comment: If you're intending to make the trellis up completely from scratch I would definitely recommend not trying to cut to length in advance, instead I would offer up lengths to the frame one at a time, mark and then cut — this way no scale drawings and no maths. [Note that if you intend to go under/over, under/over you need to cut each piece overlength.] But I believe the lattice is widely available already made up and this might be a viable way for you to do this, you'll need to compare costs at your location.

Comment: +1 to “don’t try to cut in advance”. For material purchasing planning, draw the trellis to scale and simply measure the pieces.

Comment: In your image, since the diagonals are going 45*, the longest diagonal piece is Width of your trellis / cos(45). Or W/0.707 or W * 1.414 (I'm talking about the bottom image).